# Purpose of double が in article title

Tags: grammar, particle-が

I started to read this [artcle](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10012333031000/k10012333031000.html) and I noticed there are 2 が particles in the title

> ２０００人以上の子ども**が**インターネット**が**原因で犯罪の被害

If the first が marks the 2000+ children as the subject, what is the purpose of the second が?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60821/5010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a double が because each occurrence actually belongs to a separate clause.

The first が indeed tells us that the subject of the main clause is ２０００人以上の子ども.

However, the second が belongs to the phrase インターネットが原因で "As a result of the Internet", and tells us that the subject of *that* phrase is インターネット "the Internet".

Note that by omitting the phrase インターネットが原因で,

> ２０００人以上の子どもが犯罪の被害

we see that the true subject of the main clause is ２０００人以上の子ども.